# How can you control cities in Sid Meier's Pirates?

Tags: sid-meiers-pirates

On the PC version of the game the box says that you could take control of cities and rule them yourself. How can you do that and can you get settlements too?

Comment: Which Pirates? The new one or the original one?

Comment: I didn't know there was more than 1 type. I bought mine in 2007.

Comment: You make them part of your nation. Reading some game reviews (i.e., doing some research) can help you avoid asking really basic questions here.

Comment: @YoungGuilo Well, the original Sid Meier's Pirates! came out for the C64, that is where I played it :D. Probably my most played game from age of 13 and I still play it with the VICE Emulator sometimes. And since then a big Sid Meier's Fan hehe. Sorry for offtopic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, except in two meta-ways:

1. The most common is when you successfully pillage a city after destroying a significant amount of its defending garrison. The Governor will run for the hills and you get to decide which of the four nations to invite to send a replacement. Needless to say, the nation that gets a shiny new (well, slightly used) town out of it will be very happy with this.
2. If you complete all the quests, get all the loot and max out your rank and wealth, the highest position you can earn as you retire is "Governor". Of course, at that point the game is over, so that may or may not count either...